# Addressing a h3 within a div within a div

Tags: html, css

How can I address the h3 header within the code? I've tried using `#bandz .divider h3 {padding-right: 255px;}` but it hasn't been effective

[image: Attached screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `#bandz` doesn't work is because of the double quotation marks surrounding it; you're closing `id` before you're assigning the value. [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcuy5vgo/1/) demonstrates this.